What are the best options for imputing time series that is missing lots of days
I have many months of temperature data recorded roughly every ten minutes. Except it has gaps. If the gap is an hour or so, I can linearly interpolate, but if the gap is a few days this obviously doesn't work.
What I do at the moment is take a daily average, and spline fit to get an average each day. I also subtract the average from each day to compute a rolling average of how the data varies over time by hour. Then I can fill in missing days with the hourly roll offset by whatever the interpolated spline fit says the average should be.
It kinda works, but you can see where I've spliced. Discontinuity in the gradient at the join, for example. I'm thinking I could improve by making a daily estimate of total variation every day and then interpolate that across the gaps too, but....
Surely this should be a great application for machine learning? I'm fiddling with some scikit-learn packages, but they all seem to want to have the NaN's removed before they learn.
Any pointers would be appreciated.

For what it's worth, ChatGPT says to separate days from hours as two separate variables and run randomforest. Unclear really why that should work, but I'll check.

Why do you want to impute at all? In a time series context, generally you would use models which allow either missing observations or irregularly sampled observations, and not impute. Imputation is likely to distort dynamics and is of limited value.

You are asking about a procedure without telling us what you really want to achieve with it. Could you back up a little and explain what you hope such imputation will accomplish or how you plan to use it?

Well, the post is closed now, I guess I'll leave it. But for example, suppose you have one sensor which measures temperature and a different sensor that needs a temperature correction. You could have a day of no temperature sensor, but still have the other sensor in need of correction. So I need to guess what that temperature was over the missing interval.

Hi Chris, you mention that In a time series context, generally you would use models which allow either missing observations or irregularly sampled observations. Can you recommend such. As I think I mentioned in the post, the models that I could find all wanted me to fill the gaps first. The name of model that could forecast off data with large gaps would have been a perfect answer to the question :-)

I found FB Prophet. Looks perfect !!
